# how to write efficient python code? cpp code and python code with the same logic, execution efficiency varies more than 10 times

Tags: python, performance

i am solving a problem of interview street, the cpp code i write passed all the test cases, but the python code with the same logic need more than 10 times cpu time to execution.
the problem is [zombie march](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4ff1484963063), the code is [here as a gist](https://gist.github.com/4245599)
i am wondering how to write efficient python code, aka, how to optimize this block of python code

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips

Comment: You don't need to `line.strip()` before doing `line.split()`.  `now` and `next` are `1` and `0`.  To swap them don't do `(now, next) = (1 - now, 1 - next)`, rather do `now, next` = `next, now`.  And change the name to `next_` because `next` is a builtin.  I believe `degree[p] += 1` is slightly faster than `degree[p] = degree[p] + 1`.  Finally, get rid of your while loops and replace with `for _ in range(t)`.  You're not using the loop counter anyway.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't surprise me that a compute-bound process would be 10x slower in pure Python.

Comment: @NedBatchelder considering the time complexity, the python code shouldn't be that slow,

Comment: The time complexity has nothing to do with it. You're comparing the running time of similar code written in C and in Python.  Python executes bytecodes, which is slower than executing native x86 instructions.  Additionally, names have to be looked up constantly.  "sys.stdin.readline().strip()" has to look up "sys", and then the "stdin" attribute, and then its "readline" attribute, then invoke it, then look up the "strip" attribute, then invoke that, etc.  Strip() will create a new string, etc.  Python is slower than C.  You might get it better than 10x, but there will be a multiplier.

Comment: @pengdu:  Did you time any of the changes I suggested?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski sorry to reply so late, i've tried your suggestion, the program runs slightly faster, but still can't pass. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to write the time critical parts in C or C++. This is the standard way to make python faster when the problem consists of a CPU bound target.

Look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) to extend Python with C or C++ modules

Look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to load C dlls into python and execute functions.

Personally I'd go with the 2nd option. I find it very easy to write core modules with C++ classes and expose them with some extern'd c functions into a DLL and using that DLL in python directly.